# В pycharm при быстрой печати иногда выскакивает звук ошибки и приходиться печатать снова символ

Tags: python, аудио, pycharm, печать

Иногда при печати появляется звук ошибки в pycharm.Дело именно в Pycharm, т.к. в других средах ничего такого нет.Да и вообще при печати такого не было нигде.Иногда он возникает когда символы печатаешь,не понимаю в чем дело.

Вы сами можете убедиться в этом.Попробуйте быстро напечатать строки подряд меняя поочередно язык раскладки то на русском то на английском вот так например: 'фыва', 'asdf', 'фыва', 'asdf', 'фыва', 'asdf'
именно расставляя запятую и пробел в этом случае этот глюк чаще всего появляется.

Я поменял задержку при переключении языка в windows,на самую короткую.
Убрал мерцание курсора в pycharm.Все равно иногда такое случается.Может кто то сталкивался с подобным.

Для примера видео записал,весит мало, но суть проблемы можно понять я думаю.
Очень мешает печатать.
https://dropmefiles.com/Glg0m

http://wdfiles.ru/vz22~i?c4b1c32d1c5d87165efb620a3a81741c

https://transfiles.ru/jppb8

Comment: Вообще никаких проблем. А PyCharm купленный и поломатый? На лицензионном `PyCharm 2020.2.1 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-202.6948.78, built on August 25, 2020` проблема не наблюдается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключите опцию Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Enable mnemonics in menu. Особенности таймингов/клавиатуры/системы вызывают активацию меню IDE по кнопке Alt, а Alt+Space вызывает системное меню окна, которое может издавать звуки.

Answer (score 0):

Давно решил проблему,забыл написать ответ.В общем просто поменял способ смены языка ввода с "alt + shift"  на "ctrl + shift" пару дней непривычно было,но потом привык.Вам надо найти "переключить язык ввода" и поставить удобный вариант.
Наверное у тех кто на маке сидит или линукс такой проблемы нет.Но если вы на винде и вас бесит то что при быстрой смене языка выскакивает звук ошибки и пропадает курсор, лучше наверное нет способа чем этот.
Все дело в клавише alt как я позже выяснил.